# Trigger an action when azure function is stopped c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

As the title states, is there a way to trigger an action when the function is manually stopped or restarted ?

Example, when the function is stopped I want to make an update in Azure table storage.

I searched quite a lot in google couldn't find anything meaningful, any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by stopped? You mean going into the portal and pressing the stop button for example?

Comment: @DavidG - yes thats right.

Comment: In that case, no, I don't think there is anything. I think you can only run code on startup.

Comment: I suppose you could add a singleton to the DI container, and call code in `IDispose.Dispose` but that would be a nasty hack imo.

Comment: @DavidG In my timer trigger function(used to place messages in queue trigger), the first step is to check if the full process is completed. Running status of function will be present in an azure table. 
Normally after the function is executed, the running status will be set to false. So in next run, function will continue to execute without any issues. 
If the function is stopped abruptly, status won't be updated, so next run will not start since the running status is true.

Comment: In that case, it might be better to start a transaction that will automatically get rolled back if the function stops half way through.

Comment: One possible solution would be to make use of Azure Event Grid and subscribe to Subscription/Resource Group events - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-resource-groups.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks will take a look at it.

Comment: Please mark the answer you decided to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Azure Event Grid to achieve this. Event Grids utilise the *central nervous system* of Azure by being able to intercept logs from the Azure Monitor.

Follow this tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app) to achieve exactly what you need to do however change the operation on the condition step to:

```
Microsoft.Web/sites/stop/action
```

In your logic app. You can then apply whatever logic you want to the `true` step in the Logic App

Comment: If you want to speak about central nervous system, you should know that performance wise event grid doesn't stand a chance against service bus

Answer (score 0):

1. create logic app
2. add a recurrence action (on a specified interval)
3. add an http request to the function
4. add an if action to check for `503 unavailable` from the function app
5. add an action to update your table